# editing article in Frontend changes style/language to default

Tags: joomla, styles, tinymce, edit

I have the following configuration for a site (intranet):
- Joomla 3.3.6/tiny mce
- 1 template
- 2 styles for 2 languages English and Italian
- English is default
- each style has different header color and logo.

Now my problem:

When I edit an **english** article in frontend - no problem
but
when I edit an italian article, it changes the style to default (english: other header color/logo). It happens if I change to edit mode by clicking the gear icon directly. However, if I first click on the "read more ..." button and then click on gear icon, it works just fine.

I assume the problem is somewhere in the language setting, but I couldn't fix it yet...

Is this problem already known and more importent, how can it be solved?

Thanks in advance

Comment: are you using joomla default translation?

Comment: Yes I do.

If I change to edit mode directly by clicking on edit gear icon the url is different than the one when I first click on "read more .." and then on gear icon.

direct-link:
http://localhost/site1/index.php/it/component/content/?view=form&layout=edit&a_id=3

first "read more" then gear icon:
http://localhost/site1/index.php/it/home-it?view=form&layout=edit&a_id=3

The difference is obviously that in the 1. case, there is no home-it - it is the default site of Italian.
Now if I add home-it to the url, like .../it/home-it?view=form... the layout changes to Italian as it should.

Comment: Try with toogle editor and enter code.

Comment: Do you mean toggle or google? If I toggle the editor tinymce disappears and I can just type the html code. But it doesn't solve my problem at all. Or did I did i misunderstood you?

Comment: I ment toggle. Becouse editor can sometimes mess code.

Comment: Ok. But this issue has to do somehow with a language setting. The editor doesn't make trouble. Now I tried it a little bit more and found out, whe I set "Search Engine Friendly URLs = No" then the issue is not there anymore (in the url there is the variable lang=en respectively lang=it in this mode), but when I turn it on again the problem comes back.

Comment: Now I found the reason for the problem and it's solved! I had forgotten to set the default language for the styles and further more I hadn't created an extra style for the language All. However the second was not the cause of the issue. So I hope it helps others with similar issues.